# Relationship between the spectrum of $AA^*$ and $A^*A$

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

I'm currently reading something on unbounded operators and their spectra and the author notes that the nonzero spectra of $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ are equal. $A$ here is unbounded and densely defined (on $L^2$, if that helps), but not self-adjoint. The only other useful point might be that $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ differ by a constant. This for me does not seem to help however; if $\lambda$ belongs to the resolvent of $AA^*$, i.e. $AA^* - \lambda$ is invertible, and $A^*A = AA^* + c$ where $c \neq 0$ is the constant, then $A^*A - (c + \lambda) = AA^* - \lambda$ is invertible, so $c + \lambda$ belongs to the resolvent of $A^*A$. But I guess if this was to be a proof I would expect $\lambda \in \sigma(AA^*) \setminus \{0\}$ if and only if $\lambda \in (A^*A) \setminus \{0\}$?

On the other hand, some finite dimensional tests with real matrices in Mathematica seem to suggest this result is true (i.e. that the eigenvalues of $MM^t$ are equal to the eigenvalues of $M^tM$, but the eigenvectors are not the same). I can't see why however? Do I need more hypotheses for this to be true? If not can someone provide a hint or proof? (Especially if someone can explain why zero is of particular importance too...)

Comment: More generally, $AB$ and $BA$ for any $A,B$ of the same (square) size have the same non-zero eigenvalues (their characteristic polynomials thus differ only by a power of the variable). The simplest proof of this is a nice exercise : let  $\lambda \neq 0$ and $\lambda I - AB$ be invertible. Use this to find a candidate inverse for $(\lambda I - BA)$. I think a similar proof works in the spectrum case (or can be adapted). $0$ is of importance because having eigenvalue zero is equivalent to having non-zero kernel ,  which between $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ can be created by rank mismatches.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon - thanks for the hint. It seems the candidate inverse is $I + B(\lambda - AB)^{-1}A$. This should establish equality of the spectrum right? If $\lambda \in \rho(AB)$ if and only if $\lambda \in \rho(BA)$ then $\lambda \notin \rho(AB)$ iff $\lambda \in \sigma(AB)$ iff $\lambda \in \sigma(BA)$, at least for $\lambda \neq 0$. Also, you refer to the size of the matrices, but I think this proof should work even in the infinite-dimensional case (and unbounded) case right? I don't think I've used any properties of dimension/boundedness...?

Comment: I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - if you don't mind, could you clarify why zero is of importance in this case? The candidate inverse works even if $\lambda = 0$; i.e. if $(0 - AB)^{-1}$ exists then $I + B(-AB)^{-1}A$ is still a candidate inverse for $-BA$.

The only issue appears to me is perhaps is the distinction between "eigenvalue" and spectrum, i.e. the spectra of $AB$ and $BA$ agree but the point spectra need not agree. So is it fair to say nonzero spectra agree in infinite-dimensions, but spectra (incl. zero) agree in finite-dimension?

Comment: I get what you say and I think it is correct. I need to think a little more about this, and then I will clarify. +1 for now.

Comment: Just to wrap up the above conversation : the correct candidate is $(I + B(\lambda -AB)^{-1}A)/\lambda$. I think @meaninglesspen forgot about the $1/\lambda$ factor, which by the way illustrates why this argument does not work for $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @GuillaumeGarrigos thanks for pointing this out - I'm grateful for the clarification.